# Show minimum lies on the curve at this point

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Without using Lagrange multipliers, show that the function $f(x,y)=y$ has a minimum on the curve $x^2-y^3=0$ at $(0,0)$

I have tried subtracting the function $'y'$ and $'(x^2)-(y^3)'$ to show that the new function i.e the distance becomes $0$ at $(0,0)$ but I am not sure if that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For points $(x,y)$ on the curve $x^2-y^3=0$, we have that $y\geq 0$. Thus, $f(x,y)\geq 0$ when $f$ is restricted to this curve.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by taking the Jacobian vector and Hessian matrix of the function and then see where the Jacobian is zero (i.e. local max/min). Check the top left element of the Hessian to confirm your answer. An additional check would be to check for other values of x and y in the domain to ascertain that this is the minimum.

Comment: Jacobian/Hessian of the function representing the distance or x^2-y^3?

Comment: The function itself...